# Is there a way to get back to World 1 in Super Mario 3D World?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

I just started playing Super Mario 3D World with my daughter on the Switch.

In World 1-2 we found a red (orange?) pipe that warped us to World 2, with no apparent way to get back to World 1.

We’ve now finished World 2, and a clear pipe appears at the end of the world allowing free travel between worlds 2 and 3, but there’s still no way for us to get back to World 1, and my daughter wants to “save the green fairy”.

Short of restarting the game, is there a way for us to get back to World 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else that was confused by this, Super Mario 3D World has fast travel accessible from the map by pressing “-“. In this situation you can fast travel back to World 1, even though they are not linked until you beat the World 1 castle.

Answer (score 1):

On the nintendo switch port, pressing minus will take you to a world map that allows you to teleport to any world. Very useful for me as I have to collect tanooki suits from world 3 to bring them back for champions road in world crown

Comment: This is already stated in the other answer.